# Setting up a way for different computers to access the same virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, python-venv

I'm trying to set up a system on multiple computers where I'll be able to run the some set of scripts and have it work on all of them. If I have the same version of Python installed locally all of the computers, am I able to set up a virtual environment on a network location? If so, does the Python executable need to be on the local drive or can it be in the network location?

If this isn't possible then what is the best way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You can export all dependencies with `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and prepare a script which installs missing packages on each machine.

I would personally implement script to sort `dependencies` in `requirements.txt` alphabetically and store both in a git repository and define a cron job on each machine to pull current version of `requirements.txt` from the remote and install missing dependencies and the other script to update the `requirements.txt` and push changes so they could broadcast.